# What was wrong with this question, removed by its author?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This question was posted today:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202402/how-to-use-qml-imports-without-versioning-in-qt6

I am interested in the topic and I upvoted the question. However, when I came back later to check if there is already an answer, the question was gone.

I need assistance from a user with >10k r.p. I want to know if there is an obvious reason (downvotes, close votes, something in the comments) for the removal of this question. If there is not such reason, please share the text, so I could repost the question. I really want to know its answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of the deleted question:

[image]

I think the comment there makes the OP's motivation pretty clear:

> 1) Are you sure you are using Qt6? 2) Do you get that warning in the IDE or when you run the application? I have used qmlscene to launch the .qml removing the versions and I don't get any error